# Android data storage choice for a few fixed amount of entries, sqlite or sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I wanna make an app kind of like Google keep, which has these features:

1. Storing the names, content, background color of every notes and photos (not including to-do lists, it's a little complicated), using `TextView` for notes, Custom View (`TextView` + `ImageView`) for photos;
2. Entries could change position with each other by drag and drop;
3. It could only save 10 entries at most. If there exists opening entry position, The app will fill the position with placeholder, and display all the 10 position in one screen (no scrollbar).

In my opinion, both method have some shortcomings for this situation:

Sharedpreferences: the amount of data is too much and kind of complex;

Sqlite: the data entries are limited. Besides, I think `TableLayout` is more suitable than `GridView` cus I want them display in one screen without scrollbar.

Then which data storage method should I choose, sqlite or sharedpreferences? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't confuse how you're displaying the data with where it is stored.  Also anything you store in shared prefs can also be stored in sqlite and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences is not suitable.  As you note, it is not meant for that amount and complexity of data.  As the name implies, it is meant for storing a users' preferences, not their data.

Note that SQLite support BLOB type that can be used for storing images, etc.

But you aren't limited to those two options.  The third option would be to store your data in a file, in any format you choose, e.g. you could serialize your Java objects into a file.  Since you will be dealing with a limited amount of data you don't necessarily need the capabilities of SQLite.

But on the whole, I think that SQLite is your best option.  It is better then SharedPreferences for reasons given above, and better then the 3rd option because it is built into Android and is widely used.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll try the SQLite way.